# Regex for file name parsing

Tags: php, regex

I'm very glad this forum exists as I'm not sure where else to turn with this question. I'm parsing the file name of a whole bunch of files in PHP using preg_match_all() and I want to recover 4 bits of information. The naming convention is:

_tag_99_Nice_name.extension

I need to break this down into 4 parts

1. ***tag*** : I just want the "tag" part. Tags should start and end with
   *underscore*'s
2. **99_** : sorting, this can be a 2 digit number followed by an
   underscore.
3. **.extension**  : just like a file extension. There may be more than
   one at the end. i just want the last
   one
4. **Nice_name** : this can be any set of characters allowable file name
   characters

The tricky part is that the first 3 are optional and may or may not be present so any of the following are valid examples:

```
_taggy_01_foo_bar.text
69_something.gif
_tag_some_thing.jpg
 basic.example
```

My best attempt so far is:

```
/^(?:_+(?P<tag>[a-z0-9]+)*_)?(?:(?P<sort>\d{2})_)?/
```

but this is just not working and only tries to capture the first 2 parts :(

Any ideas would be of tremendous assistance!

Comment: You should check out http://rubular.com for testing your regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** Works in all example cases (and with multiple file extensions).

```
<?php
    $pattern = "~^(?:_(?P<tag>[A-Za-z0-9]+)_)?(?:(?P<sort>\d{2})?_)?(?P<name>\w+)(?P<ext>[.]\w+)+$~";
    $tests = array(
        "_taggy_01_foo_bar.text",
        "69_something.gif",
        "_tag_some_thing.jpg",
        "basic.example",
        "_loltag_00_pretty_name.extone.exttwo.extthree"
    );

    foreach ($tests as $item) {
        preg_match($pattern, $item, $matches);
        print_r($matches);
    }
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => _taggy_01_foo_bar.text
    [tag] => taggy
    [1] => taggy
    [sort] => 01
    [2] => 01
    [name] => foo_bar
    [3] => foo_bar
    [ext] => .text
    [4] => .text
)
Array
(
    [0] => 69_something.gif
    [tag] => 
    [1] => 
    [sort] => 69
    [2] => 69
    [name] => something
    [3] => something
    [ext] => .gif
    [4] => .gif
)
Array
(
    [0] => _tag_some_thing.jpg
    [tag] => tag
    [1] => tag
    [sort] => 
    [2] => 
    [name] => some_thing
    [3] => some_thing
    [ext] => .jpg
    [4] => .jpg
)
Array
(
    [0] => basic.example
    [tag] => 
    [1] => 
    [sort] => 
    [2] => 
    [name] => basic
    [3] => basic
    [ext] => .example
    [4] => .example
)
Array
(
    [0] => _loltag_00_pretty_name.extone.exttwo.extthree
    [tag] => loltag
    [1] => loltag
    [sort] => 00
    [2] => 00
    [name] => pretty_name
    [3] => pretty_name
    [ext] => .extthree
    [4] => .extthree
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
'~^(?:_(?<tag>\w+)_)?(?:(?<sort>\d{2})_)?(?<name>[^.]+)\.(?<ext>\w+)$~'
```

But I'm not really sure, whether I understood, what of it is optional and what is not.

Comment: doesn't seem to get `tag`, `sort`, or `name` properly.

Comment: oh, the first 2 parts _tag_ and 99_ and the last part .extention

Comment: yeah, its not splitting <tag> and <sort> properly but <name> seems to come out, testing with http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/index.php

Answer (score 1):

How about this one:

```
^(_(?P<tag>.*?)_)?((?P<sort>\d\d)_)?(?P<name>[^.]*)?.*([.](?P<ext>[^.]*))$
```

Comment: YES! genius! and it seem so simple too!? I'm impressed

Comment: oh! i found an issue here if it has a double extension: name.gif.zip I just want "name" without the .gif and extension to be just "zip" :-/